# Dynamic Routing and Displaying Response as HTML

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've put together a quick example of my application -- took me a while to figure out dynamic routing via ajax.  I return JSON from a server script controller that contains my HTML that I want to render.  But no matter what I try, Angular won't render it as HTML -- only text.

**index_simple.html**

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="cmsApp"> 
    <head> 
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app_simple.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/test">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content-view" ng-view style="border:1px solid green;padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app_simple.js**

```
angular.module('cmsApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:name', { template: '{{returned_content | trustAsHtml}}', controller: 'PagesController' });
}])

.controller('PagesController', [ 
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$route',
    '$routeParams',
    '$compile',
    function PagesController($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $compile) {

        var data = { page:$routeParams.name };
        var json_url = '/mobile/route.cfm';

        $http.post( json_url,  data ).then(function (msg) {
        if( msg.data.CONTENT)
        {
            $scope.returned_content = msg.data.CONTENT;
        }               
    });
}])

.filter('trustAsHtml', function($sce){
    return function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
});
```

**Returned JSON examples from the links**

## /home

```
{"CONTENT":"The <strong>Home Page<\/strong> Content"}
```

## /about

```
{"CONTENT":"The <strong>About Page<\/strong> Page Content"}
```

The problem is that the filter will not run and render the response as HTML.  I tried injecting the filter into the PagesController and running it on the returned content when I set `$scope.returned_content` but that doesn't work either.  Is there a different way I should be calling and receiving the JSON that will allow me to render it as HTML -- as well as compile any extra Angular content I might also have embedded in the HTML? For example if my response JSON was:

```
{"CONTENT":"The <strong>Home Page<\/strong> Content -- {{extra_angular_scope_var}} "}
```

Comment: means you wand to access your routeProvider dynamically

Comment: Yes, i am accessing the routeProvider dynamically -- but it won't render my HTML -- it displays the returned content as a text string on the page. If i change the router to pull in HTML from an HTML file instead, it displays fine, but getting the content from JSON and using the trustAsHtml filter it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to import below javascript file and inject it into module.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Inject **[ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)** in angular module:

```
angular.module('cmsApp', [
    'ngRoute','ngSanitize'
])
```